Change working directory in command prompt
I was going to install pandas_datareader
so i use
pip install pandas_datareader

It shows: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\mfb81\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\mfb81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas-datareader': The system cannot find the file specified.
However if I change the working directory by using
cd C:\Users\mfb81\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts

then pandas_datareader will be installed successfully now. May I know what is the issue and is there a way not to change directory everytime?
